# syntax error while defining a String in Mule Java class

Tags: java, mule

I am trying to define the Json string to convert that into a JSONObject. When i define the string as "String jsonObj = "{"abc":"efg"}";" in mule java class, it gives me "Syntax error on token, delete this token" error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should escape double quotes with backslash:
`String jsonObj = "\"{\"abc\":\"efg\"}\"";`

Comment: I have 100 object record and each has about 10 key value pair. do i need to manually do that?

Comment: You better parse JSON directly from a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: Helpfull..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify json in set payload and then use json-to-object

Comment: I want to use the java class as a static and it's called by another java class